# Just-In-Time Debugger: Unhandled exception - how do I get rid of the error message?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

Just installed Visual Studio and I have this error message popping up constantly:

> An unhandled exception ('System.IO.FileNotFoundException') occured in
>   AddInUtil.exe [19452].
>
> The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security permissions. To debug this process, the Just-In-Time debugger must run as an administrator. Would you like to debug this process?"

So I have tried clicking `yes` and giving it administrative permission - doesn't work and Visual Studio crashes.

I've also said `no` and tried to look up to file to give it automatic administrative permission. Not working either.

What's wrong and what can I do? Please note that all I've used Visual Studio for so far is to quickly check out some written code without editing it.